# Markov or Chebyshev used Inequality here? stat

Tags: statistics, inequality, chebyshev-polynomials

Suppose $X =\{−4, −3, −2, −1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ and suppose $E[X] = 0$. Give an upper bound on $P (X = 4)$ and an upper bound on $P (X < −2)$.

Solution given as:

Let $Y = X + 4$, $E[Y ] = E[X] + 4 = 4$

$P(X ≥ 4) = P(Y ≥ 8) ≤ E[Y]/8 = 4/8$

What  happened "$P(X ≥ 4) = P(Y ≥ 8)$"?  How can we calculate for $P(X<-2)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $X=\{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$. That it takes values on that set?

Comment: We cannot use Markov's inequality here because $X$ is not a nonnegative random variable.